# External CSS file is not loading with link tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs, nginx

I'm starting a new project with Angular and facing an issue.
When I am trying to load an external CSS file with `<link>` it doesn't work but when I am using internal style with @import it does work!

Doesn't work with :`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="transmission.min.css">`

Works with :`<style>@import url('transmission.min.css');</style>`

My files are located in the same directory (root of the app) :

```
/
/index.html
/transmission.min.css
/transmission.min.js
```

My CSS and JS files are concatenated and minified with grunt but I tried without it and same result.

Here is my index.html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transmission</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="transmission.min.css">
    <style>
        @import url('transmission.min.css');
    </style>

    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="transmission">

    <div ng-view=""></div>

    <script src="transmission.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

My CSS file just contain `body{background-color: red;}`

I checked my nginx configuration twice, and everything seems to be just fine.

I also checked with Safari inspector, I can access the CSS file at `http://transmission.dev/transmission.min.css`.

But it doesn't appears in the resources tab.

[image: No CSS file here]

Moreover my Angular application loads perfectly.

If you have any idea ? :-D

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`link` tag uses `href` attribute as opposed the the `src` as you have specified. Please change and check.

Comment: accept as correct by clicking the arrow to the left of the post if this is the answer which helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="transmission.min.css">`

`link` tag uses `href` and not `src`

Hope it helps!